# Changing media query breakpoints depending on whether side panel is showing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to add some functionality to an already existing (fairly extensive) react project. I need to have a 400px wide side panel that is only sometimes showing.
Depending on screen size, it's either in the "empty" space right to the main content (that is at its max width) or next to the main content (reducing the width the content by e.g. 400px). The main content should behave in both cases according to the responsive design. That means  with the side panel showing, e.g. a 3 column layout should switch to 1 column "400px earlier".

The project uses Bootstrap 4.6 and its media queries.

The easiest way I came up with was to replace the media queries with container queries for the main content. This was a pretty straight forward find&replace, that can be easily automated. It worked great on Chromium browsers but not on Firefox (even with this [polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/container-query-polyfill), likely because of the classes named `container` in Bootstrap, see [issue](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/container-query-polyfill/issues/23)).

This is the current solution I found:

Basic example of HTML:

```html
<body>
  <div className=`site-wrapper ${ showPanel ? '' : 'full-width'}`>
    <div class="container">
    <!--- main content --->
    ...
    </div>
    { showPanel && (
    <div class="side-panel">
    ...
    </div>
    )}
  <div>
</body>
```

I then need to convert all media queries like this one below

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container{
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}
```

into this

```css
@media (min-width: calc(992px + 400px)) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .site-wrapper.full-width .container{
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}
```

Basically doing this:

1.) duplicating each media query
2.) replace in the first copy the `<breakpoint>` with `calc(<breakpoint> + 400px)`
3.) add in the second copy `.site-wrapper.full-width` to each rule (not too hard with `postcss-nested`)

Even though it works, it is pretty cumbersome and prone to errors. I wasn't able to make the "conversion" automated (maybe it's possible with something like this [find-matching-bracket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-matching-bracket))

But overall, the solution is more hacky than I want it be.

**Is there a better way to accomplish this? Or at least a good and reliable way to make the css "convertion" task automated?**

Answer (score 0):

Below is the model code. With it, you can build a selector on the basis of a shown or hidden sidebar. In this case, the background of the content block turns red when the panel is extended.

```js
document.querySelector('.show').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.side-panel').classList.toggle('active')
});
document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.side-panel').classList.toggle('active')
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.side-panel {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: .2s;
  transform: translate(-200px);
}

.side-panel.active {
  transform: translate(0);
}

.container {
  transition: .2s;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.active+.container {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-panel">
  <button class="close">X</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button class="show">show side-panel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, but the problem are "normal" style rules, but the media queries. I basically need to change the breakpoints depending on whether the side panel is showing or not.

Comment: @jost21 but there are no obstacles to use code `.active+.container {
  background-color: red;
}` inside the media query

Comment: I don't think I can achieve what I need this way. I do not need to change what's inside the {} of the media query, I need to change the media query itself. I want to preserve the rules inside the media query (those get generated by the bootstrap build process). I need a second media query with a different break point but the same content.

Comment: If I was starting from scratch, I would do something along the lines what you are proposing. And I would not use bootstrap. But I have to work with what already exists. Therefore I am looking for something that doesn't interfere with the current styles much and recycles most of what is already there. Container queries would be perfect, if they had better browser support.

Comment: @jost21 I believe that you should not try to calculate the breakpoint, but make 2 media queries for one point and for the second, with and without the active class. However, if you still want to calculate, then you can make a small js script that looks at the width of the browser window and creates a separate css with a media query.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do, but both media query have the same rules inside them. Just the second one has the additional "active " class. But I don't want to maintain both copies of rules inside the media queries.